# how do I find out the "package names" in requirements.txt when writing a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Google Cloud Function in Python. It imports the following packages:

```
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import documentai  # type: ignore
from google.cloud import storage
```

I need to put these requirements into requirements.txt. By random, I found out that they are called

```
functions-framework==3.*
google-api-core>=2.3.2
google-cloud-core>=2.2.1
google-cloud-documentai>=1.2.0
google-cloud-storage>=1.36.2
```

What is the right way to find out the package names that need to be put into requirements.txt? Is there a reference where I can find them?

Comment: It is not simple to do. The basic command is `pip freeze`. However, that will display the name of every Python package installed on your system. I typically use a Python virtual environment to verify which packages are required. Some trial and error is required. The key is to only specify the primary packages and not all the dependencies that each primary package requires.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `pipreqs`. It should generate the requirements.txt based on the root file and not everything installed on the environment.

`pip install pipreqs`

`pipreqs ./`